# Detect DRX mode (android)

Tags: android, performance, telecommunication, battery-saver

I wanted to check if my android device is going into DRX mode.

[1] I was looking for an existing app that could tell, but I haven't found one..

[2] Is there a software to connect directly to the device that will measure it ?

[3] Is there a smarter way of detecting the DRX on/off it without using an app or software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Yes, [Nemo Handy](http://www.anite.com/businesses/network-testing/products/nemo-handy-world%E2%80%99s-most-widely-used-handheld-drive-test-tool) for example, but see below. I would not expect to find any of these apps in the Play Store.

Regarding (2), yes you can use a software application such as Qualcomm QXDM to examine the signaling between the device and the network. There is a great deal of information with respect to DRX that can be captured with this software.

Most of this type of software is quite expensive unfortunately. I am not aware of any freeware that will capture the same information. You can find out more about QXDM here: [QXDM pdf](https://www.qualcomm.com/documents/qxdm-professional-qualcomm-extensible-diagnostic-monitor)

(3) It would be much more difficult, but there may be a way to detect the state of the tranceiver programmatically.

Comment: Thanks :)

I'll have a go with both